# AngularJS fires navigation event twice when coming from a link with anchors

Tags: angularjs, anchor

My home controller is run twice when I come from a sub-page that has an anchor in it:

From https://abc.com/versions#0.9.0 back to https://abc.com/ causes my HomeController to be run twice.

AngularJS seems to be unstable when it comes to anchors during the HTML5 mode. Do you experience similar issues or have found a solution for that?

The routing code is simple as following

```
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl : 'home.html',
            controller  : 'HomeCtrl'
        })

        .when('/versions', {
            templateUrl : 'versions.html',
            title       : 'Changelog'
        })

        ...
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

See if going back to https://abc.com/# still generates the double run.

Comment: Yes, it still does. Just tested it myself.

Comment: Ah, does the `home.html` file contain by any chance a tag with the attribute `ng-controller="HomeCtrl"`? That will cause a double instantiation of HomeCtrl.

Comment: Nope, ng-controller does not exist anywhere in my code. I am using $routeProvider and define the controllers there.

Comment: Well, time to break out the in-browser debugger and add a break in the controller setup; that should at least give you a indication *where* the two controllers are set up.

Comment: Thanks for the hint - found the cause: a bad directive with this inside

`$scope.$apply(function() {
    $location.path(path)
})`